# google-cloud-pubsub installation fails in coral developer board

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-coral

**Environment details:**

```
Python 3.7.3
setuptools==51.0.0
```

I am just trying to install `google-cloud-pubsub` in coral developer board using the command,

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache google-cloud-pubsub
```

When running the above command, it started installing the dependencies then after it goes for some **grpcio** build process as shown below.

**Build log:**

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: grpc-google-iam-v1, grpcio
  Building wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for grpc-google-iam-v1: filename=grpc_google_iam_v1-0.12.3-py3-none-any.whl size=18501 sha256=2be51c55f5cab3ff97efdb39e3a6be07e5c2d030ca0a47a8358a8fa1efef58b6
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-rpj8jh5r/wheels/b9/ee/67/2e444183030cb8d31ce8b34cee34a7afdbd3ba5959ea846380
  Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error
```

This process hangs for several minutes and got the error logs shown below printed.

**Error:**

```
Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/mendel/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-1u5g0n_z
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/
  Complete output (1234 lines):
  ASM Builds for BoringSSL currently not supported on: linux-aarch64
  Found cython-generated files...
  running bdist_wheel
 ......................
 lot of lines there ...!
 ......................
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 267, in build_extensions
      build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/home/mendel/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 196, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 534, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/src/python/grpcio/_parallel_compile_patch.py", line 59, in _parallel_compile
      _compile_single_file, objects)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
      return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
      raise self._value
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
      result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
      return list(map(*args))
    File "/tmp/pip-install-1pbjozx4/grpcio_3a1c8f81c7024b04bd7534fe601796ee/src/python/grpcio/_parallel_compile_patch.py", line 54, in _compile_single_file
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  Running setup.py clean for grpcio
```

**Note:** I have successfully installed `google-cloud-storage==1.33.0`

Comment: Could  you please share your  the output of python -m pip freeze ?

Comment: It seems not possible now. https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/251